# Does the distribution with density proportional to $\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}$ have a name?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request

I am wondering if a probability density, let's call it $\rho(x)$, supported on $[0,\infty)$ and proportional to $\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}$ has some "official name" attached to it. Initially I am thinking if it makes sense to call such distributions "quasi-exponential" but it seems that "quasi-exponential" is used in some other context. I also searched a lot of "heavy-tailed" distributions online but it I did not find the one which include $\rho$ as a special case... If anyone can point out a relevant reference to me it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00605-020-01483-8 you can find "sub-exponential". Heavy-tailed is more generic and could also indicate "power-law"decay.

Comment: @LL3.14 Hello, intuitively "sub-exponential" means a distribution that is lying "below" an exponential distribution (you can view "sub-gaussian" distributions in a similar way as well), but this is clearly not the case here!

Comment: Yeah, that's a point of view. I suppose that in the point of view of this paper it is indicating that there is **less** decay at infinity (which is your point here I suppose since you are talking about tails?). Here https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-probability/volume-26/issue-none/Concentration-inequalities-for-polynomials-in-%CE%B1-sub-exponential-random-variables/10.1214/21-EJP606.full you can find alpha-sub-exponential also.

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks. But it seems that only this paper used the term "sub-exponential" in this context, what I mean is that "sub-exponential" is not USUALLY interpreted in that sense... it might be the case that such heavy-tailed distribution do not have an official name attached to it...

Comment: I suppose heavy tailed exponentials would be quite clear then ? But yes, there is perhaps not a unique name ... it is a good question though

Comment: @LL3.14 If you look over the list of "common heavy-tailed distributions" here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution you will find that this distribution does not belong to anyone of them, which is quite disappointing...

Comment: Yes, indeed .... In the field I work in, it seems the term sub-exponential is often used, which is why I indicated that ... another example more probability based: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123607004259 (Section 4.2.1)

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks for this reference!